# Getting location of a direction of current location in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, direction

I want to implement a function that calculates locations' list (longitudes and latitudes) through a direction of my phone. The result can be a rectengular shape which is pointing the corners as locations.

First how can i find the device current direction which means which direction the back camera points ?

Then how can i obtain a list of location information through this direction ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location) of Google Maps Android API, the location data available to an Android device includes the current location of the device pinpointed using a combination of technologies - the direction and method of movement, and whether the device has moved across a predefined geographical boundary, or geofence.

> This is the 3 options that you can do with your app.
>
> - Using My Location layer that provides a simple way to display the device's location on the map. It does not provide data.
> - Using [Google Play services Location API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) is
>     recommended for all programmatic requests for location data.
> - And using the [LocationSource](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource)
>     interface allows you to provide a custom location provider.
>
> By using this, you can also get the different information about the
>   coordinates that you get

For more information, check this tutorial:

- [Google Map Tutorial in Android Studio: How to get current location in Android Google Map](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/android-map-app-showing-current-location-android/)
- [Google Map Tutorial in Android Studio](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1113633/Google-Map-Tutorial-in-Android-Studio-How-to-get-c)