# Android Studio show up actual position as Marker in google maps

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, gps, location

i hope somebody could help me.
i just lunched the test app to  show up google maps on my device and now i would like to show up devices position as a marker.
the position is stored in "longitude" and "latitude".
how can i use them in onMapready?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,GPSTrackerActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    if(requestCode == 1){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Double longitude = extras.getDouble("Longitude");
        Double latitude = extras.getDouble("Latitude");}}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google Play services location APIs, your app can request the last known location of the user's device. What you need here is [Fused Location Provider API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) to retrieve the device's last known location. The fused location provider is one of the location APIs in Google Play services. It manages the underlying location technology and provides a simple API so that you can specify requirements at a high level, like high accuracy or low power. It also optimizes the device's use of battery power.

To request the last known location, call the [`getLastLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#getLastLocation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) method, passing it your instance of the [`GoogleApiClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) object. Do this in the [`onConnected()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks#onConnected(android.os.Bundle)) callback provided by Google API Client, which is called when the client is ready.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
}
```

To know more about it, check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and these related SO questions.

- [How to get current location of device on google maps api v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573094/how-to-get-current-location-of-device-on-google-maps-api-v2)
- [How to retrieve current device location & show it on map fragment in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532581/how-to-retrieve-current-device-location-show-it-on-map-fragment-in-a-fragment)

Comment: I have tried the solution  but ActionBarActivity is deprecated

Comment: hmmmmmm....check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619091/getting-location-of-a-direction-of-current-location-in-android/38640175#38640175), if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be complete solution of your problem.

```
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            LatLng yourpostion = new LatLng(0, 0);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(yourpostion));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(yourpostion));
        }
    }

     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent           data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,GPSTrackerActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        if(requestCode == 1){
           Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
           Double longitude = extras.getDouble("Longitude");
           Double latitude = extras.getDouble("Latitude");
           LatLng yourpostion = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
           mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(yourpostion));
           mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(yourpostion)); 
     }
    }
```

Comment: khalil, your solution didnt work for me. i dont know how to use the values (Latitude and Longitude) from onconnected in onMapReady :-(